# Will Apache HttpClient execute throw an IOException on ALL HTTP 5XX errors?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, ioexception

The [Apache HttpClient docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,%20org.apache.http.HttpRequest)) for the `execute(HttpHost target, HttpRequest request)` method says:

> IOException - in case of a problem or the connection was aborted

If I catch the IOException, will this catch **ALL** [Server 5xx Errors](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1)?

```
try {
  response = client.execute(httpHost, request);
} catch (IOException e) {
  // throw custom Exception
} finally {
  // close response and client
}
```

The reason I'm asking is that after this logic somewhere else down the line we're doing something like the following:

```
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() >= 500) {
  // Could we ever reach this point after the code above?
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, **HttpClient *will not throw* an IOException for *any* 500/5xx response**.

An IOException occurs *only* when the low-level connection failed (eg. invalid hostname, no server listening) or the TCP pipe was abnormally broken (eg. internet connection was lost).

An 'HTTP 500' is a server response - a *valid* server response - to indicate an error condition. It has a status code, headers, and body, which is everything a 200 response has.

The documentation says the return value is "*the [final] response to the request*"; this is true regardless of the status code as long as the server was able to return *a* valid response.

Comment: Thanks for this clarifying answer.